# What is the difference in my snippets? (Node.js Newbie)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to get back from the remote site(URL) in the following node.js codes.

Case 1: Using basic HTTP module + request module

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
// Can't get back any response from remote URL
// Can't use 'res' or nothing have in res
request('http://remote.foo.com/app/lists/dosomething.json', 
    function(err, response, body) {
        console.log(body);
    }
);

var host = 'http://remote.foo.com';
var app = '/app/lists/dosomething.json?';
var url = 'param1=a&param2=b';

// I can get something to print out back
request.get(host+app+url).pipe(res);
});`
```

Case 2: Using Express + request module

```
var express = require('express')
, http = require('http')
, path = require('path')
, net = require('net')
, url = require('url')
, qs = require('qs');

var request = require('request');
    //.....
app.get('/test/foo.json', function(req, res) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(req.url, true);
    var query = qs.parse(url_parts.query);

    var host = 'http://remote.foo.com';
    var app = '/path/dosomething.json?';
    var url = 'param1=a&param2=b';

    //the following line, the same code above Case 1 
    //can't get any result, just blank..
    request.get(host+app+url).pipe(res);
    res.end();
});
//....
```

Can anyone explain it?

Thanks

Comment: In your second example, why do you end the response? You don't need to manually close a stream when another stream is piped into it.

Comment: @PaulMougel,Thanks Super Great! it works! I added it (res.end()) habitually and have never thought it might could be the reason. Happy New Year. Thank again you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment a little bit:

When you `pipe()` a readable stream into a writable stream, by default `writable.end()` is called when the readable stream emits the `end` event (see [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options)). This means that when you pipe streams, you don't have to explicitly close the destination stream by yourself: it is automatically closed when the source closes. This should make sense: when the source stream ends, the destination stream doesn't have anything to do, and should indeed close.

In your second example, you first pipe a readable stream (`request`) into a writable stream (`res`), but the very next instruction closes the `res` stream, without even reading anything, since the first `read()` call is executed on the next tick (see [source](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/_stream_readable.js#L714-L716)). The solution is then to remove `res.end()`, since it will be handled automatically.

As a side note: if you need to keep the destination stream open for some reason, you can pass `{end: false}` to `pipe`.